# while loop with semicolon java

Tags: java, while-loop

Why do we use while loop with a semicolon (`;`) just after it?

I have this code as an example:

```
public static void Register()
{String name,code;
int posStudent,posCourse;
System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------");
System.out.println("Enter the name of the student");
name=in.next();

while ((posStudent=VerifyTheStudentName(name))==-1);

System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------");
System.out.println("The list of available courses is:");
for(int i=0;i<courses.size();i++)
    System.out.println(courses.get(i));
System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------");
System.out.println("Enter the course code");
code=in.next();
while((posCourse=VerifyTheCourseCode(code))==-1);
students.get(posStudent).registerTo(courses.get(posCourse));
}
```

so what does while do here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A while or for loop with a semicolon after it is a loop with an empty body.   All of the work is done by the loop condition logic / iteration logic.  So

```
    while ((posStudent = verifyTheStudentName(name)) == -1);
```

is equivalent to

```
    while ((posStudent = verifyTheStudentName(name)) == -1) {
    }
```

*Please don't write loops with empty bodies the first way.  It is so easy for the reader to not notice the semicolon and think that the statement after it is supposed to be the loop body.*

So, what does the statement mean?

1. Loop while `verifyTheStudentName(name)` returns `-1`.
2. When some other value is returned, capture it in `posStudent`.

Capturing the value in a conditional like this is a fairly common idiom ...

However, there are reasons to suspect that *this* example code might be *incorrect*.  (If you repeatedly call the same function on the same argument, you would expect to get the same result each time, leading to a potential infinite loop.  But it does depend on the context ...)

Comment: so if VerifyTheStudentName(name) returns -1 everytime it will be an infinite loop? because when it returns -1 once it will return it after and after. VerifyTheStudentName is a method that verifies names in an ArrayList. So if the same name is not present in this ArrayList once, it will not be present in the second and third loop and so on.

Answer (score 5):

In case the while condition does all the "work",no loop body is needed.

Comment: It depends, because here, name and posStudent does not seems to change, so if the condition is true once, it'll infinite loop

Comment: Or in case, that the condition is changed by another Thread and we want to wait for that event.